# Bind a TextBox to an object's property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I know you would say this question is duplicated, but I haven't found any working solution.
So an easy scenario:

I have a textbox and a button:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox" Text="{Binding st.SomeText}">
<Button Click="Button_Click">Push</Button>
```

I have a class named Something:

```
public class Something
{
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
}
```

I have an object in the MainWindow class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Something st;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        st = new Something();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(st.SomeText);
    }
}
```

So I want to type something to the textbox, press the button and get a message contains the textbox's text, but I keep getting empty messages instead.
What should I modify?

A lot of 'solution' said to use a Stackpanel or something and set the DataContext, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Please check how to do binding. http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/

Comment: Get a basic understanding from the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first have to set the `DataContext` property to the instance of your ViewModel which in this case is `SomeThing` class, so you need to set the context in the CodeBehind of the `xaml` form like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Something st = new Something();
        this.DataContext = st;
    }

}
```

and then in your view i.e xaml file you can set the binding of the control that which particular property to bind for textbox like:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox" Text="{Binding SomeText}">
```

and you should be using [Commands](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM) instead of using the Click event of Buttons, if you want proper MVVM pattern in your WPF application.

You might want to look at [How to Implement MVVM in WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level)

Comment: OK, I had to set the DataContext in codeBehind.I wonder how can I do it in the view though... :)
But I have a working basic (not that basic) program to start with. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

How were you setting the data context?

The data context is where WPF looks for it's bindings. It seems you are trying to bind to your code-behind, in which case you need to set your DataContext to the object itself, and change the field st to a property.

```
private Something _st;
public Something st
{
    get
    {
        return _st;
    }
    set
    {
        _st = value;
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("st");
    }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    st = new Something();
}
```

However, if you're always wanting to bind to things inside st, it might make more sense to set the data context to the Something directly:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    st = new Something();
    this.DataContext = st ;
}
```

and simply bind like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText}">
```

This means you don't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, or have st as a public property on your Window (But you should on Something, firing a change notification in the setter of SomeText).

Comment: Your first example also requires that `st` is a public property, not a field.

Comment: Oops, my mistake - didn't notice it was a field!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a button click on this scenario I believe a much simpler method would be for you to bind the text in the text box in the button_click method itself:
cs file:
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string myText;
        myText = txtBox.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(myText);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="txtBox">
```

SO what happens here is Im getting the txt that i have typed on the textBox through the Name of the text box. And in the Button_Click method Im binding the text in the text box to a string and displaying the text through the Message.Show dialog box.
Thanks Hope it helps helps. Cheers